# Copy single value into multiple columns using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code here. I need to place the value entered by the user (say integer 10), compute an operation on it and enter the answer into the row defined by my table.

I am not able to copy the same value in the 4 columns. How should I change my code?

```
<html>

<table>
   <tr>
     <td class="demo"></td>
     <td class="demo"></td>
     <td class="demo"></td>
     <td class="demo"></td>
   </tr>
</table>

Enter Input:<input type="text" name="test"/>


<script>
  function testfunc()
    {
      var tt=document.getElementsByName("test")[0].value;   
      document.getElementsByClassName("demo").innerHTML = tt*20;
    }
</script>

<button onclick="testfunc()">TEST</button>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` gives you a list of elements and there is no method or property on that list to manipulate all the elements in it. To manipulate the elements you'll have to iterate through the elements individually.

```
  cells = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){
    cells[i].innerHTML = tt*20;
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BzmBX/

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
function testfunc(){
  var tt=document.getElementsByName("test")[0].value;
  var tds = document.querySelectorAll('td.demo');
  var nrtds = tds.length;
  for(var i=0; i<nrtds; i++) {
    tds[i].innerHTML = tt;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use, id's instead of classes.

Try

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testfunc()
    {
          var tt=document.getElementById("test").value;
          //alert(tt);
          var log;
          log = tt*20;
          for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
              document.getElementById("c"+i).innerHTML = log;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border=1>
   <tr>
     <td>Col1</td>
     <td>Col2</td>
     <td>Col3</td>
     <td>Col4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td id='c1'> </td>
     <td id='c2'> </td>
     <td id='c3'> </td>
     <td id='c4'> </td>
   </tr>
</table>
Enter Input: <input type="text" id="test" name="test"/>
<button onclick="Javascript:testfunc();">TEST</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, only problem with the code is that the Javascript function [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) *returns a set of elements which have all the given class names*.

So the correct Javascript code would be:

```
<script>
  function testfunc() {
    var tt = document.getElementsByName("test")[0].value;

    // Loop through all demo table columns returned.
    demoColumns = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
    for (var i = demoColumns.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      demoColumns[i].innerHTML = tt * 20;
    };

    // Incorrect.
    // document.getElementsByClassName("demo").innerHTML = tt*20;
  }
</script>
```

In your example you were trying to set the inner HTML on a collection as opposed to a single DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

You might probably want to restrict to changing the contents of the table only. So adding a id "demoTbl" for the table, and using document.getElementById("demoTbl").getElementsByClassName("demo") will only search for element with class "demo" in the table id="demoTbl"

```
 <html>

    <table id="demoTbl">
       <tr>
         <td class="demo"></td>
         <td class="demo"></td>
         <td class="demo"></td>
         <td class="demo"></td>
       </tr>
    </table>

    Enter Input:<input type="text" name="test"/>


    <script>
      function testfunc()
        {

          var tt=document.getElementsByName("test")[0].value;   
          var sel = document.getElementById("demoTbl").getElementsByClassName("demo");

          for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
            sel[i].innerHTML = tt*20;
          }

        }
    </script>

    <button name="test" onclick="testfunc()">TEST</button>

    </html>
```